# Extension for PHP to ignore SVN conflicts

Tags: php, svn, conflict

I'm sure I'm not the only one who has tried to `switch` the latest code changes to the live server from SVN just before heading home, only to find that some blockhead has modified files directly on the server and now you have five PHP scripts marked as **conflicted**, the site is **down** and you get **yelled at** by your wife for being late for dinner because you had to resolve all the conflicts manually because a rollback is out of the question.

I think it would be awesome if there was an extension for PHP that wouldn't die with a parse error for `unexpected T_SL` when encountering a conflicted file, but would instead parse it using only the working copy version of every conflict.

```
<<<<<<< .mine
changes_my_stupid_coworker_made(); // This would be executed
=======
my_important_changes(); // This would NOT be executed
>>>>>>> .r9
```

Is there such an extension or something that can be user for similar effect?

Comment: I can only imagine this would be a very complex plugin to write while keeping peformance up... while the problem itself can be avoided by not giving everyone access to live environments, hell if you need to make edits to a live environment outside of version control you're likely doing something wrong (in your workflow)...

Comment: I agree, nobody should have to touch anything on the live environment and our workflow strictly forbids doing it without a very compelling reason. Still, it happens - maybe because the definition of "compelling reason" varies wildly from person to person.

Comment: Your coworkers are using the "jenga" anti-pattern. See [The Daily WTF: Release management done Right](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Release-Management-Done-Right.aspx) for info on it.

To enforce Subversion, use JB Nizet's suggestion of using SVN Export and set it to overwrite the server's files.

Someone's work got lost? Shucks, they failed to follow the process. If things are really urgent, tell them to modify the sources in the "tagged" branch and notify the project manager to clean up the mess (i.e. a new tag will be needed, and the old tag is no longer "clean").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would really be the worst way of fixing the problem.

- Don't ever let anyone edit files directly on the server. The files could be made read-only (or the culprit could be fired)
- Don't update the server directly from the SVN repository: update a working copy, run all the unit and integration tests on this working copy, then tag the revision, and export the working copy to the server

If people just can't work correctly, don't let them work anymore.

Comment: We're already tagging the revisions and using them in the update process, but they can still be conflicted if there are local changes on the server. They can't even be spotted when testing the changes in the integration testing environment. We also need to allow write access on the files because otherwise `svn switch` couldn't touch them either.

Comment: Don't make the server serve files from a working copy. Make it serve files from an exported working copy, with limited file access.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the live environment forcing theirs-full, can still cause problems (see previous comment) but that prevents conflicts from happening. From there on you can work on not having to make changes to a live environment outside of version control.

Out the top of my head

```
svn up --accept theirs-full
```

We made sure all developers have a way to update a live environment, be it very strict. We can't update through command line on live servers, but we have a central script on a server on which we can configure projects on it, then we can give update commands through the script. The script will then do a diff first, checking conflicts and update if nothing is wrong and it sends multiple people and a teamlead responsible for the project an email with the cmd output.

It's pretty neat, prevents terrible screw-ups and really late nights.